# Visual C++ : create icon for application in other resource

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, icons

I have an picture (file type is png) and I want to make this as an icon for my app in Visual C++.
When I add from resource: if I choose Icon>new: will be has a editor icon (that not what I want). If I choose import, it will create an other folder contain my picture import, and I cannot use it as an icon.

So, who help me about this, please.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about copy-paste image data into new icon resource?

Comment: Yes. I have thought about this solution. but It cannot. I cannot copy file from this folder to other folder of resource.

Comment: Yes but open it as PNG, then CTRL+A to select all, then CTRL+C to copy image , then create/open new icon and CTRL+V to paste image.Maybe you just need to correct transparent color.

Comment: Sorry. But when I open PNG, my cursor just is magnifier. and I cannot edit anything. So, CTRL+A or CTRL+C cannot do anything. Can you tell me more,please.

Comment: I have converted PNG to ICO file by other software. but after that, when I compile, file exe still not use this file as an icon. Can you help me this step ?

Comment: What type of project you are using? MFC/ATL? then just be sure that icon has identifier IDI_MAIN for change it in MainDilog/Application class using LoadIcon

Answer (score 0):

Stop fiddling around an image you might like. Search Download appropriate icons from many of sites available. Few of them:

- www.freeiconsweb.com
- www.iconarchive.com
- www.bestfreeicons.com
- www.iconfinder.com
- www.freeiconsdownload.com